# Chart series fixed range

Tags: highcharts

My chart consist of website statistics (time on x-axis, views on y-axis) and its series are updated by `addPoint()` method every fifteen minutes. However after gathering more and more data I don't want to show all of them, just limit them to one last hour.

To give you an example - if my series consist of data:

```
2013-08-21 12:15 2000
2013-08-21 12:30 3000
2013-08-21 12:45 2500
2013-08-21 13:00 2300
2013-08-21 13:15 2700
2013-08-21 13:30 3000
```

I want only have 2013-08-21 13:30 to 2013-08-21 13:30 on the graph.

Comment: Did you consider shifting parameter in the addPoint() ?

Comment: No, how this method is different (better?) from Barbara's answer?

Comment: I didn't know about the shift parameter.  Very nice!  Since you don't start out with the max number of points, you'll still need the check.  But, you could set a boolean when you get to the max number of points and use it for the shift parameter.  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append-and-shift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you add a point, I'd check if the 1st point was < however far back you want to go.  If it is, remove it.

```
if (chart.series[0].data[0].x < time cutoff) {

    chart.series[0].data[0].remove();
}
```

Since you're doing a consistant time interval, you should be safe with just checking the 1st point.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.remove()

Another option based on the comments above:

```
var bShift = false;
if(!bShift && chart.series[0].data[0].x < time cutoff)  
    bShift = true;
chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, bShift);
```